# Java program to transfer from SQL database to another in java : column field = reserved word

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to run my java program, in which I have to transfer data from a DB to another one.

Well, the program works but one of the column field is named "public", and when I'm trying to transfer that data using jdbc, it crashes with the following statement:

> "incorrect syntax near from keyword 'public'".

I've tried to load the column field as `[public]`, `(public)`, `` `public` `` works in SQL syntax but not in the program, since it has to check equivalence for "public", so "'public' is returning false.

Some code sample when i load the datas :

```
  String publicDb = iArboFromExtranet.get(i).getString("public");
```

Some code sample when i transfer it :

```
private static final String PUBLIC = "public";

IArbo.set(PUBLIC, Strings.nullToEmpty(publicVar))
```

By the way, i cant rename the fields since i'm working for  IT services industry. Its not our database

Comment: Can you post some code on how you try to do it? Can you rename the columns that result in problems?

Comment: Sure, here it is :
when i load datas : 
String publicDb = iArboFromExtranet.get(i).getString("public");

when i transfer :
IArbo().set(PUBLIC, Strings.nullToEmpty(publicVar))

Unfortunatly, i cant rename. I'm working in an internship, its not my database, its not even my company database. We are a service company

Comment: without SQL query and full exception is is totally unclear question. Then I will vote down. What to do with "java"?

Comment: It is a java program which transfer datas from a DB to another. I'm sorry if i'm unclear, as i said i'm not native english speaker. I try my best

Comment: This not an "english" problem, I'm not Englishman too ;) Full stack of exception, code of the layer contacting directly with DB (Your code hasn't direct contact), queries etc details is base to correct answer, not lottery

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a framework to generate your SQL, and you use a reserved word as a column name, you have a (tough?) choice to make:

1. Update the implementation of `IArbo` to quote reserved words (or all names).
2. Don't use `IArbo`.
3. Don't use a reserved word as a column name.

Comment: none of the choices are possible, but i will try to contact the owners of the database to see if they can change the field name!

Comment: You could subclass IArbo and override the method that does the lookup to add/remove quotes as necessary. That may be your quickest path.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're building SQL insert and/or update queries. Quote everything, so if the database field is MyField and the table is MyTable your query should have "MyTable" and "MyField" for this particular field. In Java you can build the string by escaping the double quote with a backslash:

```
queryString = "insert into \"MyTable\" (\"MyField\"...) values ('whatever'...)";
```

Comment: Or just quote `"public"` and leave the rest unquoted.

Comment: In my experience, it's best (and easier) to do them all. There's usually no way at run time to determine what words are reserved by the particular DBMS, so you'd have to build your own list.

Comment: The thing is i got local variables that contains the column field, and methods are building the queries dynamically for me (the .set method that i edited in my post)

Comment: Typical, most preferred quotation sign is `[` and `]` and have no problems in C-alike programming languages.

Comment: I've tried those, but when the method is trying to establish an equivalence between [public] and public, it obviously fails :(

Comment: I still don't get the issue totally, probably a translation thing, try iArbo.set("\"" + PUBLIC + "\"", Strings.nullToEmpty(publicVar))

Comment: Answer TOTALLY doesn't fit to question. Ho do You deduct this?

Comment: @Jacek Prior to the OP adding example code, it fit just fine. It's still the essence of the issue.

Comment: @JacekCz The answer was good at the time it was posted. The question changed.

Comment: Its the same! The field name "public" is not recognizable due to quotes. The program did not find an association by the same name. For example, in C, stcmp("[public]", "public") would not return 0. Trying to be understandable xD

Comment: Library (unknown to me and probably to asker) has unknown problem, no chance via quoting string from external resolve this problem (not generating next)

Comment: @tekjcvd Are You author of iArbo ?

Comment: From the class, yes, but not from the database. I'm just trying to get datas from i_arbo table in database "base_extranet" and transfer it to i_arbo from "base_tampon" for example.